# Upgraded ubuntu to 19.04 - pip broke in virtualenvs (distutils problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6, distutils

I have upgraded my ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 and then to 19.04. I've noticed that my virtualenvs stopped working and located the problem in `distutils`.

I've installed `python3-distutils` and I can run `python3` > `import distutils` just fine, because this relates to python 3.7.

I can also do the same with python (2.7).

The problem is that a lot of my envs are python *3.6* where if I run `import distutils` I get:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  6 2017, 08:44:35) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/emihir0/mjartan/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
>>>
```

How can I resolve this?

The same goes for when I try to make a new venv through pycharm. I can make a new venv for both 3.7 and 2.7, but as soon as I try to make 3.6 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpb_tuwex1pycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/tmp/tmpb_tuwex1pycharm-management/setuptools-40.8.0/setuptools/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import distutils.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.core'
```

And well, the main problem of course is that when I try to just run `pip` in my virtualenv, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emihir0/venv_name/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/home/emihir0/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/emihir0/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/emihir0/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/emihir0/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, src_prefix
  File "/home/emihir0/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 10, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig as distutils_sysconfig
  File "/home/emihir0/venv_name/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
```

EDIT:
I've fixed it by downgrading my `python3-distutils` to:
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-i386/python3-distutils_3.6.5-3_all.deb.html

However, this is not a proper solution. How shall one fix this properly?